# Looping through values in twig and replacing empty values

Tags: symfony, csv, twig

The title is a bit ambiguous I know, but let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I am attempting to generate a CSV based on data pulled from a doctrine query in my Symfony2 CRM. The data retrieved is based on OpenCart Product and Attribute data, as well as some bespoke information which is irrelevant for this issue.

Each product can have up to 5 different attribute values, named A, B, D, L1 and L2. However, some products do not have all of them, only A, B and L1. The CSV requires each attribute value to be in a separate cell - so the headers are as follows:

> ATTRIBUTE: A | ATTRIBUTE: B | ATTRIBUTE: D | ATTRIBUTE: L1 |
>   ATTRIBUTE: L2

And then I loop through in my Twig file as follows:

```
{% for attribute in row.product.attributes %}
    {% if attribute.text is not null %}
        {{ attribute.text }},
    {% else %}na,{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the product has all 5 attributes, the structure of the CSV is fine. However, if the product only has 3 attributes, it means that all of the subsequent values are pulled back a cell, meaning that the other data is under the wrong headings. I tried checking for values first:

```
{% for attribute in row.product.attributes %}
    {% if attribute.attributeName.name == "A" %}
        {% if attribute.text is not null %}
            {{ attribute.text }},
        {% else %}na,{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And I did this for each possible attribute name, but unfortuantely this does not work since if the name does not exist, it just skips it anyway. I'm having trouble trying to think of a way to loop through these attributes and entering a n/a if it's non existent - I'm sure there is a way but I don't know what it is.

For reference, here is the controller code that's generating the data for the CSV:

```
public function adminCsvAction($filter) {

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Project');
    $stages_repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Stage');
    $users_repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');

    $results = $repository->getSearchResults($filter);
    $users = $users_repository->findAll();
    $stages = $stages_repository->findBy(array('deleted' => 0), array('sortOrder' => 'ASC'));

    $filename = "export_".date("Y_m_d_His").".csv";

    $response = $this->render('AppBundle:pages:csv.html.twig', array('data' => $results,'users' => $users, 'stages' => $stages));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename);
    return $response;
}
```

The `Project` Entity has various mappings, one of which links to the Product table in OpenCart which means all attributes and linked values are accessible via this.

Any help in this is much appreciated.

Comment: Programming in twig (as compared to php) can be painful.  Personally, I would write a php function that accepts the product data as input and returns a csv ready array with all five slots filled out with something.

Comment: I agree with Cerad, `twig` should be used for presentation, not modification

Comment: Have you already tried var_dumping each variable ? I had a similar problem and var_dumped to find out that, translated to your case, I have to use `attribute[0].text` instead of `attribute.text`

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with Cerad from comment section -  that is not the job for `Twig`. In case your **really** need to do it, I would try roughly something like this:

```
{% set allAttr = ["A","B","D","L1","L2"] %}

{% for attribute in allAttr %}
    {% if row.product.attributes[attribute] is defined %}
        {{ row.product.attributes[attribute].text }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I guess the `is defined` is critical here...

Comment: This is a good idea, however `row.product.attributes[attribute]` won't exist, since the A, B, C etc. is referred to in another entity called attributeName within the Attributes entity array.

Comment: And that is why `is defined` will skip the whole `if` if it does not exist, right?

Comment: No, what I mean is that will never exist, as the attribute name is within another Entity. Basically, using the code you've suggested comes up with no results everytime (i.e. na,na,na,na,na). It's assuming that row.product.attributes has an array key of "A" or "B" etc. when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. Using what Jovan Perovic suggested, I came up with this:

```
{% set allAttr = ["A","B","D","L1","L2"] %}
{% set prodAtts = [] %}
{% for row in data %}
    {% set existingAtts = [] %}
    {% for att in allAttr %}
        {% if att not in prodAtts %}
            {% set prodAtts = prodAtts|merge([att]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for rowAtt in row.product.attributes %}
        {% set existingAtts = existingAtts|merge({(rowAtt.attributeName.name|trim):(rowAtt.attributeName.name|trim~'_'~rowAtt.text|trim)}) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for prodAtt in prodAtts %}
        {% if prodAtt not in existingAtts|keys %}
            {% set existingAtts = existingAtts|merge({(prodAtt):(prodAtt~'_na')}) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
        {% set orderedAtts = existingAtts|sort %}
....
```

Then the loop for each row thereafter. I used the attribute name with an underscore in order to be able to sort it correct (as it only sorts by value not key) then used preg_replace to remove it along with any instance of the name so I just ended up with the value.

Bit of a lengthy - and probably over thought - solution but it does work!